# How to calculate the total differential at a point?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

For example, the total differential of f(x,y)==E^(x*y) at (2,1) is E^(2) (Dt[x] + 2 Dt[y]),

However,

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_, y_] := E^(x*y);
Dt[f[x, y]] // Simplify
% /. {x -> 2, y -> 1}

(*E^(x y) (y Dt[x] + x Dt[y])*)

(*0*)
```

How to get the result E^(2) (Dt[x] + 2 Dt[y])?

Comment: `D[f[x,y],{{x,y},1}] /. {x -> 2, y -> 1}`

Comment: What about using the rule {dt_Dt -> dt, x -> 2, y -> 1} instead of {x -> 2, y -> 1}?

Comment: Thanks. @Henrik Schumacher

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Would you please write a complete code? @jose

Comment: Dt[E^(x y)] /. {dt_Dt -> dt, x -> 2, y -> 1}

Comment: This can work. Thanks. @jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must protect "Dt[x_]"  otherwise if x gets a numeric value, this evaluates to zero

One possibility is to rename "Dt[_]", do the replacements and then undoing the renaming.:

```
Dt[f[x, y]] /. {Dt[x] -> d1, Dt[y] -> d2} /. {x -> 2, y -> 1} /. { 
  d1 -> Dt[x], d2 -> Dt[y]}

(*E^2 (Dt[x] + 2 Dt[y])*)
```

Comment: This method is very good, thank you. @Daniel Huber